# Reading an image url with beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read a picture from a website. This is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01.html'
page_request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_request.text,"lxml")
img_src = soup.find("div", {"class": "media-item"})
print img_src
# <div class="media-item"><img alt="Photo of James Harden" itemscope="image" src="https://d2cwpp38twqe55.cloudfront.net/req/201804182/images/players/hardeja01.jpg"/>\n</div>
```

I'm interested in the url of the jpg image. I can write some regular expression to get the jpg but there must be some easier way to do that.

What is the best way to extract the url of the jpg?

Comment: You can take a look at my answer if you're looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in several ways. This as one of such approach:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
image = soup.find(itemscope="image")['src']
print(image)
```

Output:

```
https://d2cwpp38twqe55.cloudfront.net/req/201804182/images/players/hardeja01.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method that works with [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors):

```
img_src = soup.select_one('.media-item > img')['src']
```

You can also try out [`Requests-HTML`](http://html.python-requests.org/):

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01.html')
```

```
>>> r.html.find('.media-item > img', first=True).attrs['src']
'https://d2cwpp38twqe55.cloudfront.net/req/201804182/images/players/hardeja01.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solution:

```
img_src = soup2.find("div", class_="media-item").find('img')['src']
```